# Can react hooks can ensure setState and props always be the same instance in the component lifetime?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function SomeComponent(props)
{
    const [state, setState] = useState();
}
```

For component like this, can react ensure `setState` and `props` always be the same object instance?

As I test, I believe it is. And in many official examples, `setState` and `props` are not added to the `useEffect`'s dependence list.

But I didn't find any document about this. And is there any other object like them?

Answer (score 1):

[useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

From the official react hooks docs

> **Note**
>
> React guarantees that `setState` function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the `useEffect`
> or `useCallback` dependency list.